# how do i control where bison puts c++ code?

Tags: c++, header, bison

I'm trying to control where bison outputs the prologue sections of the code while using it in c++ mode and in the defines mode (i.e. write out a header)

Basically, I have :-

```
%{
  // stuff that should go into the parser.tab.hxx
%}
%{
  // stuff that should go into the parser.tab.cxx
%}
```

I'm using bison 2.3 and don't have easy access to bison 2.5 (which seems to have some sort of functionality for doing the same).

I'm also aware that this can be done since some of the exmaples online seem to be able to achieve this... Any help?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to Bison 2.5 (or even 2.6.2) if it does what you need?  It's open source; it is easy to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy workaround: in a file with the name you want the source file to have, put

```
#include "parser.tab.cxx"
```

and nothing else. Similarly for the `.hxx` file. (Make sure your build system doesn't try to build all `.cxx` files in the directory.)

Comment: So what you're suggesting is that I do something like 
dummy_source.cpp contains '//stuff to go into parser.tab.cxx \n #include "parser.tab.cxx"' and dummy_source.h contains '//stuff to go into parser.tab.hxx \n #include "parser.tab.hxx"' and then build dummy_source.{cpp,h} ?

Comment: @owagh: yep. Or upgrade to Bison >=2.5, it's really not that hard.

Comment: well i can compile it, but convincing my systems team to maintain something that I've compiled myself as opposed to something available in the distros is a bit of a challenge.